# Load ServletConfig

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-3.0, servlet-listeners

I want to load the ServletConfig of an specific Servlet from inside a ServletContextListener.
I tried to do that from inside `public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce){}` using the ServletContext but the operation `sce.getServletContext().getServlet("SERVLET_NAME").getServletConfig()` but I can't because getServlet() of ServletContext is deprecated.

Is that possible load ServletConfig in another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the API specification says:

> As of Java Servlet API 2.1, with no direct replacement.
>   This method was originally defined to retrieve a servlet from a ServletContext. In this version, this method always returns null and remains only to preserve binary compatibility. This method will be permanently removed in a future version of the Java Servlet API.

Alternatively, you can access `getServletRegistration(String servletName)` which returns a `ServletRegistration`. It has an API which enable you to access Init parameters and Servlet name same as `ServletConfig`, plus extra methods to access Servlet mappings and run-as role.